# Reroute one URL

Tags: software-rec, proxy, url, http

I am looking to reroute one particular URL to another, for example : `http://website.com/page1.html` to `http://website.com/page2.html` on a third party server only on my machine. But I still want it to reply as if it was page1.html. Is there a way to do that on a client UNIX ?

Alex
PS : If any clarification is required, please tell me

Comment: Are you looking to make this work such that if any program (wget, FireFox, etc) requests `page1.html`, the client machine automatically redirects the request to `page2.html`?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a web proxy.

Comment: justin : yes, basically, on my machine, as I would in /etc/hosts/, say "any requests to that url get changed to this one" and then any program that I open _thinks_ he's calling one page while actually the OS is requesting another one
gilles: no, a proxy is external and makes me run all my connection through it. /etc/hosts/ is just the OS requesting different host but the program still thinks it's calling the original URL, plus it's as simple as adding a line in /etc/hosts. I need something built-into unix.

Comment: Please clarify "on a third party server only on my machine".  Do you mean that you want to fool your machine (and only your machine) into retrieving page2 when you ask for page1?  I assume by "third party server" you mean it is one you do not have control over. EDIT: Never mind, your comment clarifies this.  Didn't see it before posting.

Comment: That's right, just fool my machine.

Comment: A proxy is probably the easiest way to do this and it could be run on your machine, i.e. it needn't be external.  `/etc/hosts` works because it just affects name resolution, but what you want to do is at a higher level and therefore more difficult.  Perhaps you could set up a reverse proxy for website.com (on your machine) and then add website.com in /etc/hosts pointing at 127.0.0.1.  Then configure the proxy to know where the real website.com is and to rewrite page1 to page2?

Comment: sound complicated though, any opensource currently existing and easy to use proxy on UNIX ? (Mac OS X if that helps)
But there's no low-level way to do this ?

Comment: Looking on google a bit, I see I should create a Proxy Auto-Config file, PAC, how and where do I create that ?

Comment: From what I'm gleaning, If you're running Apache, this would be a simple addition to the conf files to allow the following of symbolic links. This way, a directory would be a link to another and apache would follow it.

Comment: @Alexandre: For commenters to see your replies to their comments, you need to include @name in your comment, the way I did here; only one per comment will work. (I just happened to wander by.) A PAC file wouldn't particularly help here, you need a proxy to redirect `page1` to `page2`, and it might as well leave all other traffic unchanged, so you'd just point your browser at the proxy.

Comment: @gilles, thanks, I will look into that, however won't a proxy use up a lot of processing power ?

Comment: @Alexandre: Compared to a web browser rendering the page, very little, I'd guess.

Comment: @Gilles Yeah I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted another comment yesterday, but it is not here now!

Anyway, it seems that a proxy is probably the way to go, despite your reservations.

A proxy can run on your machine, and therefore needn't be external.

Changing /etc/hosts to fool your browser into connecting to site2 instead of site1 just affects name resolution and is easy.  Getting your machine to fetch page2 instead of page1 is much harder.

You could probably do it this way if you do not want to configure the clients to use a proxy:

- Add website.com to /etc/hosts pointing at 127.0.0.1
- Set up a reverse proxy on your machine and configure it to point to the real website.com.
- Configure the proxy to fetch page2 when page1 is requested.